# Getting the Embedding of Text in a Dataframe

Tags: bert-language-model, embedding, transformer-model

So I have a dataframe which contains 5 articles. Each article has been tokenized sentences using nltk. Here's an example of the article.

[Example Article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNQnS.png)

I want to get the embedding of each sentence in each of these articles using BERT. But BERT only limits 512 tokens, while this article is a long document. What's the solution?

What the solution to do to get the embedding?